# Using Deprecated and removed in future methods

Tags: ios

Suppose a method (for ex. A ) deprecated in ios 6.0 and removed in ios 7.0.I released my app with ios 6.0 as a base sdk.My doubt is that if method A in ios 6.0 gets called it will perform its work or not and same method gets called in ios 7.0 what will be the result.

Thanks in Advance for your response.

Comment: Use `if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(newMethod)])` to the new version, and if not, use the old method.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile against the 6.0 SDK, it will work on future iOS versions. 
If you compile against the 7.0 SDK, there is no guarantee at all. I wouldn't even bet that it works on a device running 6.0.

Comment: This is incorrect, calling the method on iOS7 will cause your app to crash since the method has been removed on iOS7, compiling against the 6.0 SDK will not make the method magically reappear on iOS7.